# Using TFTP in docker, getting a timeout

Tags: docker, tftp

I have a tftp server running in a docker container.

I am using this image and I tried different ones: https://hub.docker.com/r/jumanjiman/tftp-hpa/ .

When I try to `get` a file from the tftp server, it just says: `Transfer timed out`. Do you guys have an idea? I am on macOs

Comment: is the docker container running on your mac or another system? have you verified that it has any network connectivity?

Comment: The docker container is running on my system. Yes I exposed the port

Answer (score 2):

TFTP is a protocol that uses port 69 when "negotiating/stablishing" a transfer but the actual "data" transfer is carried out on a different ephemeral port. If you exposed only port 69 and the traffic on the ephemeral port range is somehow blocked you will receive a "Transfer timeout error"

Answer (score -1):

If the traffic actually does flow, I’ve seen TFTP implementations that were extremely sensitive to the block size read by the server. Try increasing it if configurable, but keep it a bit below your network’s MTU size (often 1500 bytes)